# unexpected T_USE, expecting '{'

Tags: php, syntax

```
<?php

$wordFrequencyArray = array();

function countWords($file) use($wordFrequencyArray) {  //error here
    /* get content of $filename in $content */
    $content = strtolower(file_get_contents($filename));
```

Here is a snippet of a code i am using.

I am getting error on the 3rd line. I have all the matching braces .What might be wrong?

Comment: That use syntax only works for anonymous functions.

Comment: i have just posted a part of the code .the closing brace is there .

Comment: @Maerlyn: what do you mean by anonymous functions?

Comment: @shiven http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: @shiven, simply put, remove `use` and put `global $wordFrequencyArray` inside the function instead. And read the docs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be:

```
$countWords = function($file) use($wordFrequencyArray) {
  //...
};
```

Answer (score 9):

Only [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) may have declare a `use` statement, hence the error message warning you that an opening bracket is expected instead of the `use` statement.

To circumnavigate having no `use` statement, you can either add more parameters and pass it to the function, or in some cases call the variables as [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: **Never** use `global`, you can always add another parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but adding to the discussion.

I struggled through Name Space Declarations and Use commands. In the end I found the problem was simply that I was trying to make the declaration in the function where I was going to use the item. This caused my script to fail with the above error message. Moving the declaration to the beginning of the php script after the

Answer (score -2):

try

```
<?php

$wordFrequencyArray = array();

function countWords($file) {  
global $wordFrequencyArray;
 /* get content of $filename in $content */
 $content = strtolower(file_get_contents($filename));
}
```

Comment: this won't work if codebase is required in function/method call

Answer (score -2):

make it something like:

```
$wordFrequencyArray = array();

function countWords($file,$wordFrequencyArray)  {
    /* get content of $filename in $content */
    $content = strtolower(file_get_contents($filename));
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The outer `$wordFrequencyArray` variable will be out of scope inside the function, which is probably not what he wants.

Comment: yes i don not want it to be static ,retain its value in each iteration

Comment: @Mischa, he don't need it to use as static. Check comments please.

Comment: Check what comments? Seems @shiven is saying I am right. It's possible to pass `$wordFrequencyArray` like this, but it seems he wants to update the variable and then use it outside the function too. That won't work with your code.

Comment: Yeah ofcourse. If he want the static property then it is not possible by this way. He should register global variable or if he is in OOP then create a static array in Class and access it by `MyClass:$wordFrequencyArray` though?